# Android: Layout Generated By Java Does Not Look Same As XML

Tags: java, android

At this part in the development I am trying to add Linear Layouts on Screen on a button click. I tried to make it as similar to the XML generated ones but it does not code out the same. [Screen Shot here.](http://postimg.org/image/v5d6iie1p/) The EditText does not show and there is not top padding. After the Java is the Layout I am basing it off of

FYI: The top two layouts are what I am aming for with this java

This is My code so far:

```
 LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
                layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((getDP(80f)), LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));


                TextView numberView = new TextView(this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams tvParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getDP(80f),getDP(10f));
                numberView.setLayoutParams(tvParams);
                numberView.setText(numOfItems+".");
                layout.addView(numberView);

                EditText optionText = new EditText(this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams etParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getDP(80f),getDP(100f));
                numberView.setLayoutParams(etParams);
                numberView.setHint("List Option "+numOfItems);
                layout.addView(optionText);

                insideScroll.addView(layout);
```

And the XML:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:weightSum="100"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                    android:layout_weight="10"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:text="1."
                    android:id="@+id/tvItem1"/>
            <EditText
                    android:layout_

weight="90"
                        android:layout_width="100px"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:hint="List Item 1"
                        android:id="@+id/etItem1"
                        android:paddingTop="50px"/>

            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why don't you stick to xml and make whole layout in xml ? There is reason for doing view from Java code ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to stick to having most of your layout as XML.
You can inflate the XML programmatically and then, if needed, change any dynamic content within the newly created layout.